# SQL Data Reader into Label - Value doesn't display

Tags: sql, asp.net, oop, sqldatareader

> DB-Acess.cs

This is where the Public SqlDataReader getEmail is initialised.

```
public SqlDataReader getEmail(string UserName)
        {
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            //string noemail ="noemailsaved";
            SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            newCmd.Connection = conn;
            newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            newCmd.CommandText = "Select Email from dbo.EMPLOYEE where Username ='" + UserName + "'";
            SqlDataReader reader = newCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string email = reader["EMPLOYEE.Email"].ToString();

            }
            conn.Close();
            reader.Close();
            return reader;
          }
```

I'm using OOP and calling the function in asp.net page and want to display the value in a label. Below is the code I'm using to call the function.

```
SqlDataReader reader = dba.getEmail(pname);
lblEmail.Text = reader.ToString();
lblEmail.DataBind();
```

Instead of seeing the Email address of the Employee i'm seeing **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader**

Please help in correcting this error.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ERRORS**

1. Return type of the function **getEmail** is `SqlDataReader` and you are expecting `String` i.e. an Email.
2. Declaration of email in `string email = reader["EMPLOYEE.Email"].ToString();` is inside `while loop`. Therefore, `email` becomes local to the `while loop`. It will not recognize outside the loop.
3. And you are returning `reader' an instance of`SqlDataReader`,but you were expecting a`String`.
4. In you second code block, what your doing is not wrong(it won't give error) but that is not what you are expecting to get. You should be declaring a `String` variable eg. `email` and assign the function to it(or you can directly assign it to `lblEmail` Text property.

**SUGGESTION**

The way you are checking `ConnectionState` in `if(conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")` may give you the desired result but is not recommended. Instead you should check like this `if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)`.

**Now the most awaiting part: The improvised code: lol!**

**UPDATE**

```
public string getEmail(string UserName){
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed){
        conn.Open();
    }
    //string noemail ="noemailsaved";
    string email="";
    using(SqlCommand newCmd = new SqlCommand()){
        newCmd.Connection = conn;
        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "Select Email From dbo.EMPLOYEE Where Username = @uname";
        newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname",UserName);
        using(SqlDataReader reader = newCmd.ExecuteReader()){
              while (reader.Read()){
                   email = reader["Email"].ToString();
              }
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
    //reader.Close();
    return email ;
}
```

For setting the `Label` Text

```
lblEmail.Text = dba.getEmail(pname);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I prompt an error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." any idea what causes this?

Comment: try disposing the SqlCommand & reader: `if(newCmd!=null){newCmd.Dispose();} if(reader!=null){reader.Dispose();}` or you can use `using` statement

Comment: try the Updated Code

Comment: IndexOutofRangeException for Employee.Email. Any idea on how to correct this? @jonju

Comment: Ofcourse  it should be `Email` only not `Employee.Email`. How could i missed it?

Comment: So easy yet so difficult lol !! Anyway really glad I could helped you

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going wrong here:

1) You are setting the `string` **email** to the value of the reader. Which because you are declaring it inside the reader, will never be able to be used. You will lose scope immediately.

2) You are doing this:

```
lblEmail.Text = reader.ToString();
lblEmail.DataBind();
```

This is setting the label to the name of the reader (the instance), not the value the reader is producing. No reason to bind, either.

A better way to do it is

```
lblEmail.Text = email;
```

**Make sure you declare the email variable outside the reader**

Answer (score 1):

So there are so many issues going on, I decided to write this comment as the beginning to an appropriate solution.

First your method is called getEmail -- shouldn't it return the email (in other words, a `string` instead).

```
public string GetEmail(string UserName)
    {
        string email = string.Empty;
        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        //string noemail ="noemailsaved";
        SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        newCmd.Connection = conn;
        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "Select Email from dbo.EMPLOYEE where Username ='" + UserName + "'";
        SqlDataReader reader = newCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            email = reader["EMPLOYEE.Email"].ToString();

        }
        conn.Close();
        reader.Close();
        return email;
      }
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
lblEmail.Text = db.GetEmail(pname);
```

That should at least get you going.  You should also look into using `parameterized queries` as well as the `using` statement.

- [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I prompt an error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." any idea what causes this?

Comment: @Omesh -- that means your original code isn't working as I didn't change that.  Where is the error coming from?  At first look, should you call reader.Close() before conn.Close()?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's cause you are calling `ToString()` on reader object and thus it just printing the classname fully qualified `reader.ToString()`.

Moreover, you are dong it wrong. Current code shouldn't work since you are returning reader which has already been closed and thus you can't read from it. Rather, you should change your method to return the email and use it like

```
public string getEmail(string UserName)
        {
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            //string noemail ="noemailsaved";
            SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            newCmd.Connection = conn;
            newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           // Hopefully your query returns a single email record
            newCmd.CommandText = "Select Email from dbo.EMPLOYEE where Username ='" + UserName + "'";
            SqlDataReader reader = newCmd.ExecuteReader();
            string email = string.Empty;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                email = reader["EMPLOYEE.Email"].ToString();

            }
            conn.Close();
            reader.Close();
            return email;
          }
```

Moreover if your query returns a single `email` value then use `ExecuteScalar()` rather like

```
        string email = newCmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

Now you can assign it in caller

```
lblEmail.Text = dba.getEmail(pname);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I prompt an error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

any idea what causes this?

Comment: @Omesh, somewhere else in your code you have already opened another reader object which is still open. check it.

Answer (score 0):

string q,d;
        int ano=0;

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SANDEESQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=agent demo;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from po where agentno=@ano", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ano",ano);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        d = dr["date1"].ToString(); 
    }

    dr.Close();

    Label1.Text = d+ "";
   does not show value of date in lablel
```

Comment: I fail to see how your answer relates to the question?